# How to start and stop a background script/cmd with crontab?

Tags: bash, cron

How can I start and then stop a tcpdump cmd/(or bash script) via crontab? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference to run tcpdump or any other command via crontab. You can create a script that stops tcpdump at the beginning and start it again. crobtab.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
killall tcpdump
var=$(date +%G%m%d-%k%M)
/usr/sbin/tcpdump -i eth0 -C 10 -w ~/$var.txt
```

Then run crontab for this script

```
00,15,30,45 * * * * /path_to_crontab.sh
```

That means this script will run every 15 minutes at everyday

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just didn't know killall :-( Great!